# How can I partially fill density chart in R highcharts based on X axis?

Tags: r, highcharts

How can I add partial color to the density graph based on x axis?

For example, I want the color to be red if it is lesser than 0 and green if it is greater than 0.

```
library(highcharter)
data <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
hchart(density(data), type = 'area')
```

Comment: Have you tried to use threshold with negativeColor? http://jsfiddle.net/5zgtmfmt/

Comment: No, but I want threshold to be x axis? That if x is greater than 0 then everything to the left of 0 should be red and everything to the right should be positive....You know how can i achieve that?

Comment: Could you paste a mockup as an image?

Comment: Here is the sample link image, I hope this makes sense 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gx3w.png

Comment: You need to use zones: http://jsfiddle.net/resczkwv/, Docs: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bubble.zoneAxis